# How to store a row index for very large (csv) files?

Tags: csv, indexing

I am working with large csv files (>> 10^6 lines) and need a row index for some operations. I need to do comparisons between two versions of the files identifying deletions, so I thought it'd be easiest to include a row index. I guess that the number of lines would quickly render traditional integers inefficient. I'm adverse to the idea of having a column containing lets say 634567775577 in plain text as row index (followed by the actual data row). Are there any best practise suggestions for this scenario? 
The resulting files have to remain plain text, so serialisation / sqlite is not an option.

At the moment, I'm considering an index based on the actual row data (for example concatening the row data, converting to base64 or the likes), but would that be more reasonable than a plain integer? There should be no duplicate row within each file, so I guess this could be one way.

Cheers, Sacha

Ps: I heavily modified the initial question for clarification

Comment: It is possible, but it is essentially reinventing the wheel. You should put a dataset this size in a proper database - doubly so if you need random access to the rows.

Comment: "The resulting file still needs to be human readable" - A human reading 1 line/sec of a file with 10 ^6 rows will be there for three years. That is a way to say file is not human readable by definition - you can export the relevant records that a humam should look at as a reduced CSV later.

Comment: I can see that the discussion deviating in an unexpected way. I'd like to clarify: I do not look specifically for a python solution, and I am aware of 'proper' database solutions that handle millions of rows easily. However, I am working on an HPC and I will need plain text format files. The python tag was misleading, it's there because raw data is parsed line by line in python. My motivation to ask the question was to prevent an index in a csv file (that's what I meant by human-readable) to be super 'wide', for example: 1122448928304;12;23;12.5 (csv format). Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: ok - so, yes, Python is still a proper language for that - but then, I can figure out exactly what is the index you need - just a byte offset for the starting point of each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use regular numbers.

Python is not afraid of large numbers :) (well, to the order of magnitude you described...)

just open a python shell and type `10**999` and see that it doesn't overflow or anything.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there's no actual bit limit for integers. In Python 2, there is technically -- an `int` is 32 bits, and a `long` is more than 32 bits. But if you're just declaring the number, that type casting will happen implicitly. 
Python 3 just has one type, and it only cares about memory space.
So there's no real reason why you can't use an integer if you really want to add an index.

Answer (score 0):

Python built-in library contains SQLite, a self-contained, one-file-fits-everything DBMS - which contrary to normal perception can be quite performant. If the records are to be consulted by a single application with no concurrency, it compares to specialized DBMS thta requires a separate daemon.

So, essentially, you can dump your CSV to a SQLITE database and create the indices you need - even on all four columns if it is the case.

Here is a template script you could customize to create such a DB - 
I guessed the "1000" numbers for number of insert a time, but it could
not be optimal - try tweaking inserting is too slow.

```
import sqlite3
import csv

inserts_at_time = 1000

def create_and_populate_db(dbfilename, csvfilename):
    db = sqlite3.connect(dbfilename)
    db.execute("""CREATE TABLE data (col1, col2, col3, col4)""")
    for col_name in "col1 col2 col3 col4".split():
        db.execute(f"""CREATE INDEX {col_name} ON data ({col_name})""")

    with open(csvfilanem) as in_file:
        reader = csv.reader(in_file)
        next(reader)  # skips header row
        total = counter = 0
        lines = []
        while True:
            for counter, line in zip(range(inserts_at_time), reader):
                lines.append(line)
            db.executemany('INSERT INTO data VALUES (?,?,?,?)', lines)
            total += counter
            counter = 0
            lines.clear()
            print("\b" * 80, f"Inserted {counter} lines - total {total}")
            if counter < inserts_at_time - 1:
                break
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I commented in above section, this is not an applicable solution (probably, I'll have to see about that). I need pure text files, since this task is just a small part of a much larger workflow in which all steps require plain text files. 
But cheers up for sqlite, it's (usually) awesome!

Comment: maybe it is time to revise the steps. A proper DBMS server could certainly feed the data to consumers in more convenient ways than GBsize txt files.